# How to get the resource name out of the clicked image in a gridView?

Tags: android, gridview

I have a GridView and want to get the name of the clicked Resource (e.g. R.drawable.foo1) and I don't know how.

Here is the place in my Fragment where I want to get the Name:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                // TODO HERE I WANT TO GET THE NAME
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I have the following adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.foo1, R.drawable.foo2, R.drawable.foo3
    };
}
```

Comment: But why you get `Ressource`? instead of directly get `Drawable` from `mThumbIds` using `Position` in your `onItemClick(.....)`

Comment: How should the code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make mThumbIds as public:

```
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.foo1, R.drawable.foo2, R.drawable.foo3
};
```

And in onItemClicked() get the image resource name as follow:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
           int id = mImageAdapter.mThumbIds[position];
        }
```

Comment: But how the get the R.drawable.foo1 then out id the Id?

Comment: Try getResources().getResourceEntryName(id) or getResources().getResourceName(id) to get the resource name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826494/image-is-not-attaching-in-gmail-and-facebook

Comment: it gets image name only..and when i attach it becoms file type

Answer (score 2):

Add `mThumbIds` in your `Fragment` and directly get `Drawable` from `mThumbIds` using `Position` in your `onItemClick(.....)` like.

```
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            //mThumbIds[position]; get particular Drawable from mThumbIds

        }
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826494/image-is-not-attaching-in-gmail-and-facebook

Comment: image name is getting but extension changes

Answer (score 1):

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
                int res = ((ImageAdapter)parent).getResource(position);
            }
        });
```

then in adapter use this method to get image resource:

```
public void getResource(int pos){
return mThumbIds[position];
}
```